# Why can't add anon_upload_enable=yes into configuration file?

Tags: vsftpd

Here is my /etc/vsftpd.conf in debian8:

```
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
local_root=/home/ftp
anon_root=/home/ftp
```

I can connect the ftp server with `open 192.168.1.100` (My local ip is 192.168.1.100).

Why can't connect the ftp server when to add two lines into /etc/vsftpd.conf?

```
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_enable=YES
```

Comment: What do your logs say?

Answer (score -1):

1.anonymous_enable=YES---> To enable Anonymous users (No authentication).
2.local_enable=YES -----> To enable local users able to login
3.write_enable=YES ----> To make it writable
4.chroot_local_user=YES ----> To Change their Root directory
5.local_root=/home/ftp ---> Default directory for ftp users
6.anon_root=/home/ftp ---> This is root Directory for anonymous (un-authentiated users)
7.anon_upload_enable=YES --> To enable Anonymous users upload files
8.anon_mkdir_enable=YES -->To enable Anonymous users make directory

You should be configured your server either to be authenticated or un authenticated....cannot be both.